# Creating MimeMessagePreparator using existing MimeMessage Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail, mime

I have a MimeMessage object with fields already set.

How do I create a MimeMessagePreparator with this existing MimeMessage object?
I tried passing existing mime message object to MimeMessageHelper constructor but it doesnot work.
Below is the code snippet:

```
MimeMessage msg=new MimeMessage();
msg.setFrom("abc@crop.com");
msg.setTo("xyzc@crop.com");
msg.setSubject("Test mail");
msg.setText("Test Mail java sender",false);


MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = new MimeMessagePreparator (){
        public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception{
         MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg);//creating helper with existing mime message object
        }
    };
    

mailSender.send(messagePreparator);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but someone may find it useful:

```
MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = mimeMessage -> {
            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
            messageHelper.setTo("toemail");
            messageHelper.setFrom("fromEmail");
            messageHelper.setSubject(subject);
            messageHelper.setText(body, false);

        };

        sendMail(messagePreparator);
```

**P.S:** If you are using any template, I assume `body` is that templated message-body. If you are using `html` templating, set it `true` too.